# Passport local temporary password (change on first login)

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-local

For security reasons we create users and send them a **temporary generated password**. At their first login the user should change it's password before continuing navigating protected pages.

I'm using an express/node website running a **passport-local** module. Registering, login in users all work. But I'm kind of lost on best practices for users to change their password on the first login.

My idea was to do the following :

```
/* POST login page. */
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/dashboard/users',
    failureRedirect: 'pages/login'}, function(err, user, info) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('')
      return res.render('pages/login', {title: 'Login', error: err.message});
    }

    if(!user) {
      return res.render('pages/login', {title: 'Login', error: info.message});
    }
    return req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return res.render('pages/login', {title: 'Login', error: err.message});
      } else if (user.firstLogin) {
        return res.redirect('/change-password'); // <- First login
      } else {
        return res.redirect('/dashboard/users');
      }
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

As you can see I have a simple boolean (tinyInt 0-1) set in my database (defaults to 1). Afterwards I'll set a post method which after a successful change, the boolean would be set to 0.

Is this a correct way ('a' not 'the' :p )? How about the security?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It definitely is *a* correct way. I'd say it perfectly suits your needs. I personally like how the usage of your database field directly reflects the business logic behind it.

Alternatives, though I'm fan of your solution, could be:

**1**

Adding a `lastLogin` date field to your database which defaults to `NULL`. This would store a datetime stamp whenever the user logs on. You could use it as an implicit check if the user has ever logged on before. I personally prefer having explicit columns for their purposes (like you're doing with your `firstLogin` column) because the purpose of the column and business logic of the application is very clear from it.

**2**

Another alternative would be to store when a user has last updated his password i.e. `lastPasswordChange` defaulting to `NULL` for new users. Same reasoning as above. Could be useful if you'd want your users to change their passwords every `n` days.

Security speaking I'd say this'd be solid. As long as your `firstLogin` field defaults to `1` then there'd be no way a new user could skip the password change upon first login.

However, when a user updates his password, be sure to either update the `firstLogin` field in the same query *or* perform both queries inside a transaction. This way you'll always be sure both the password **and** the `firstLogin` field are changed. If for some reason either query would fail you'd have a user who already changed their password and is asked/forced to change it again or a user who has a randomly generated password without being asked to change it. 
Doing it inside the same query would make sure both, or neither are updated at the same time. Doing it inside a transaction leaves you with the option to fail/rollback the transaction when either query fails.

On another note, your code could be written like this (both your way and this is correct, it's just a matter of preference and visual):

```
/* POST login page. */
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', { 
        successRedirect: '/dashboard/users',
        failureRedirect: 'pages/login'
    }, function(err, user, info) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('')
            return res.render('pages/login', {title: 'Login', error: err.message});
        }

        if(!user) {
            return res.render('pages/login', {title: 'Login', error: info.message});
        }
        return req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return res.render('pages/login', {title: 'Login', error: err.message});
            } 

            // Using if/else if/else makes no difference since if the first if is executed
            // in both cases nothing else will execute due to if/else or the return.
            // In case the above statement resolves to `false` the effect wills till be the same

            if (user.firstLogin) { 
                return res.redirect('/change-password'); // <- First login
            }
            // The else is not necessary due to the return in the line above.
            return res.redirect('/dashboard/users');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

If you'd like a more specific answer to either question, I'd need a more specific question.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. Thank you for the reply, helped me alot.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a good thing to move the "check first time login" logic into a separate middleware which executes for all "logged in routes".

With your suggestion above the user can simply navigate away from /change-password after redirection?

Comment: I don't mind the user navigating away from the page, but as soon as he wants to login again: he will be asked again to change his password. I'll probably log the whole situation to check this out.